# IBM Watson Knowledge Studio - Get mention class from entities

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery, watson-knowledge-studio

When annotating mentions using Watson Knowledge Studio, one have the posibility to specify the mention class: "Specific", "Negative" or "Generic" mention ([Establishing a type system](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/knowledge-studio/typesystem.html#typesystem)).

Once the annotation have been completed and the Machine Learning Model is created, it can be deployed to a service (for ex. Watson Discovery). It would be useful to be able to query entity types, with the result including the specification of it's mention class.

In later questions related to this ([IBM Watson Knowledge Studio - Annotating negative / negated mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800879/ibm-watson-knowledge-studio-annotating-negative-negated-mentions)), from a year ago, there was still no possibility to get this information from new text.

So the question is, is it still not possible to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

We are still investigating to enhance this in future. Currently mention attributes cannot be extracted in NLU.